# How to remove characters from String Value?

Tags: java, string, trim

I am storing below number as a string. How can I remove the first three characters & last one character from the string?

```
String No = "00098000002208";
```

Comment: What have you tried? See the [substring method of String class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).

Comment: Is the format of string going to remain same always?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and probably fastest way would be to just use the base string function `substring`:

```
String input = "00034000004409";
String output = input.substring(3, input.length()-1);
```

We could also try doing a regex replacement:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("^.{3}(.*).$", "$1");
```